# Unsure of how to query a subdocument that's been defined with another schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate an array of results that consists of a subdocument's fields.

These are my schemas:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    zID: Number,
    password: String,
    email: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email
})

const orgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email
})    

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    date: Date,
    code: Number,
    org: orgSchema,
    signed: [userSchema]
})
```

This is where I query my database:

```
event.find({org.id: req.user.id}).then((events) => {
    console.log(events);
    let eventArray = [];
    events.forEach((event) => {
        eventArray.push({id: event.id, name: event.name});
    });
    res.render('organization', {events:eventArray});
}, (error) => {console.log(error)});
```

The problem here is with the ".find" query, I've only been receiving errors about the "." being an unexpected token. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Enclose inside double quotes `event.find({ "org.id": req.user.id })`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that fixed the error but still doesn't return any results from the query

Comment: Where is your `org` schema?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet my bad, I've just included it